# Firefox cookies not being saved

Tags: 11.04, firefox

I'm running the latest Natty beta and I've realized that cookies are not saving under Firefox.

Passwords and history save normally, but cookies do not. I have check the settings in Firefox and it is set to save history.

This becomes a problem because I am using two-step authentication for Google so every time I close a window I need to check my phone for a new code.

Also strange is that every time if I ever mistype my password entering Google (on the first bad type) they give me a captcha box to fill in.

These irregularities do not happen under Win XP sp3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have not included the cookies in the option "Clear history when Firefox closes". Also make sure you set the cookies to be kept "until they expire".

Another alternative, which is what I do, is to use the [Biscuit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/220876/) extension. It allows to mark certain cookies to be kept, even if Firefox is set to delete cookies when closing.